# how to add multiple values to array at once

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray

i hav a 3 values to be added always to the current index...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObject:[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:myFirstObject,mySecondObject,myThirdObject,nil]];
```

Or you can simply add a dictionary to an array, which indexed by any value (like an NSNumber from int).

Answer (score 0):

```
for (foo;bar;baz) {
    [myMutableArray addObject:myFirstObject];
    [myMutableArray addObject:mySecondObject];
    [myMutableArray addObject:myThirdObject];
}
```